# Two different words for getters by reference vs getters by copy

Tags: c++, documentation, cpu-word, getter

Consider the following example :

```
class MyClass
{
    // Getters by copy ?
    public:
        inline std::string fullName() const {return _firstName+_lastName;}

    // Getters by reference ?
    public:
        inline const std::string& firstName() const {return _firstName;}
        inline const std::string& lastName() const {return _lastName;}

    // Data members
    protected:
        std::string _firstName;
        std:::string _lastName;
}
```

In the documentation of my code, I would like to distinguish between getters by reference (direct access of the class data members) and getters by copy (access to data constructed on class data members). What words can I use to name these two different categories ?

Comment: The more formal term for "getter" is "accessor" (which is actually grammatically worse), but I've never heard of a word to distinguish between getting by reference and getting by value. Maybe "value-getter" and "reference-getter" would do.

Comment: Why would you need a return-by-copy version? If somebody wants to use the name they'll make a copy anyway.

Comment: In the example, what I name "getters by reference" are firstName and lastName, and what I name "getters by copy" is fullName (but maybe fullName is not even what programmers call a getter). The question is how to name the first category and how to name the second one ?

Comment: @jrok When I first learned programming at university they insisted on get-by-copy

Comment: Also this is a subjective question

Comment: subjective yes, but honestly I think he has it right. first and last are const-ref returns, full is synthesized and thus byval returned. And fwiw, if you're documenting this I would simply tag them all as "read" properties and call it good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first question that comes to mind is why you want to distinguish the operations in the name. Specially since that separation implies that you are leaking details of your implementation to the users and losing encapsulation.

Consider for example that during profiling of the real application you find out that 90% of the time callers use `fullName()` and don't make copies, then you might want to modify your type to *cache* the result and avoid the cost:

```
class MyClass {
   // ...
   std::string _fullName;
public:
   const std::string& fullName() const {
      return _fullName;
   }
   // One of the options for caching: update on set
   // Could use other, like update on first request...
   void setName( std::string firstName ) {
      _firstName = std::move(firstName);
      _fullName = _firstName + _lastName;
   }
};
```

If your naming convention differentiates both types of functions, then you would either have to seek all uses of the function in your project and replace them for a change in the *implementation*, or else your function would be *lying* as the naming implies a copy, but the implementation does not.

That being said, I have seen this done in the past, where accessor that just return a reference to the member were named either by the nember or `getMember`, and operations that create new objects were named as a sentence with a verb that implied the construction: `composeFullName` to imply that there is a cost associated with calling the operation. This change in the naming conventions, where I have seen it, was specific to operations where the *cost* of executing it was high.

Comment: Ok, so for you all my functions firstName(), lastName() and fullName() are of the same category (all are getters), even if some return by copy and some others return by reference ? Furthermore, what is your point of view on the comment "When I first learned programming at university they insisted on get-by-copy" on my question ?

Comment: The fundamental difference between getFirstName(), getLastName(), and getFullName() is the latter is contrived, quite frankly a convenience to the invoker, that could have just as well done the same thing. The latter will be byval just because of its generate-on-the-fly, but the former two would likely be best returned by const-ref, just for the sake of cutting down on the copying.

Comment: @Vincent: As a simple comment, you should not think of methods as how they are implemented, but rather what they represent. Programming is modeling a domain, and the first, last and full names are properties of the object `Person` in that domain (I assume `MyClass` represents a person). Regarding what to return, const-reference when possible, value when needed (a synthesized field like `fullName` cannot be returned by reference --unless you store it internally as in the example with the cache, and then the refactor will be source code compatible).